# check_snmp_load Return code of 255 is out of bounds

Tags: icinga

My Icinga 1.14 web interface reports "Return code of 255 is out of bounds" despite the check returning an OK status. (The nrpe binary is *not* used to execute commands.)

```
   /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_snmp_load.pl '-H' '10.0.4.84' '-C' 'Y5Rap0I' '-2' '-T' 'netsl' '-w' '10,8,5' '-c' '15,12,10'
```

The above command renders **Load : 0.00 0.00 0.00 : OK** from the command line on the Icinga satellite but in the Icinga classic web interface I see 
**Return code of 255 is out of bounds**

Comment: Could a load of all zeros could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I changed:

```
check_command       check_snmp_load!netsl!10,8,5!15,12,10
```

to

```
check_command       check_snmp_load!'netsl'!'10,8,5'!'15,12,10'
```

in /etc/icinga/devices.d/fnord-services.cfg

So all I did was add single quotes to the arg values in my services.cfg.

commands.cfg contains the lines:

define command {
    command_name    check_snmp_load
    command_line    $USER1$/check_snmp_load.pl -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -C $USER5$ -2 -T $ARG1$ -w $ARG2$ -c $ARG3$
}